# What do NDS, NDD, and DDS stand for in encoding VEX instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel, machine-code

From [Intel's x86 manuals, Vol2](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), Section 3.1.1.2: *Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table (Instructions with VEX prefix)*

> **NDS**, **NDD**, **DDS**: specifies that VEX.vvvv field is valid for the encoding of a register operand:
>
> - VEX.NDS: VEX.vvvv encodes the first source register in an instruction syntax where the content of source registers will be
>     preserved.
> - VEX.NDD: VEX.vvvv encodes the destination register that cannot be encoded by ModR/M:reg field.
> - VEX.DDS: VEX.vvvv encodes the second source register in a three-operand instruction syntax where the content of first source
>     register will be overwritten by the result.

I think that it has something to do with "non-destructive source" and I presume that's what NDS stands for. What do the others stand for, and how does that affect an instruction's encoding? On a similar note, why do they even matter - as the AMD manual does not include any reference as far as I can tell to these terms?

Comment: I assumed it was non-destructive source, too.  I hadn't even noticed the NDD and DDS variants in FMA (and maybe other insns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Intel [APX docs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html) (Advanced Performance Extensions: REX2 and EVEX for legacy integer instructions like `sub`, and finally an encoding of `setcc` that writes a full 32/64-bit register: [Intel APX Architecture Specification - July 2023 Revision 1.0](http://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/784266)):

- `NDD` stands for **new data destination**
- `NDS` stands for **non-destructive source**
- DDS isn't mentioned in that doc

Presumably the pre-2018 SDM editions used the same expansions for the acronyms.

---

I haven't looked at the AMD manuals, but I assume they chose some other way to indicate which operand is encoded by the `VEX.vvvv` field, for instructions that use it.

Intel uses this notation to remind you / make it clear which operand is the vvvv field.  It's already redundant, because the "Operand Encoding" table for each instruction shows which operand is encoded in which field.

---

Update: **Intel removed them from their manual** maybe in the Nov 2018 update.  They were also removed from the ["future extensions" manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/c5/15/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf) rev 035 in October 2018 which has instruction listings in the same format as the vol.2 manual, and has a revision table where they provided this changelog:

> Removal of NDD/DDS/NDS terms from instructions. Note: Previously, the
> terms NDS, NDD and DDS were used in instructions with an EVEX (or VEX)
> prefix. These terms indicated that the vvvv field was valid for
> encoding, and specified register usage. These terms are no longer
> necessary and **are redundant with the instruction operand encoding
> tables** provided with each instruction. The instruction operand
> encoding tables give explicit details on all operands, **indicating
> where every operand is stored and if they are read or written**. If vvvv
> is not listed as an operand in the instruction operand encoding table,
> then EVEX (or VEX) vvvv must be 0b1111.

So that tells us that the purpose of those NDD/DDS/NDS tags was to indicate which operand was which, and whether they were read or write.

---

*Non-Destructive Source* is a phrase used elsewhere in the same volume of the manual (see below), so I'm pretty confident that's the correct interpretation of `NDS`.

I think the obvious interpretation of `NDD` is *Non-Destructive Destination* (where the SSE2 versions of shifts annoyingly are destructive).

It's unclear what `DDS` is supposed to stand for.  "Destructive Destination-Source" doesn't fit, because it's the *other* source reg that gets overwritten.

---

#### [Intel manual vol2](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) Section 2.3.5 The VEX Prefix:

> The bit fields of the VEX prefix can be summarized by its functional purposes:

> - **Non-destructive source** register encoding (applicable to three and four operand syntax): This is the first source operand in the instruction syntax.  VEX.vvvv.

(inverted: 1111 for xmm0, 0000 for xmm15. As described later, the inversion avoids overlapping with valid encodings of 32bit-only [`LES` and `LDS`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LDS:LES:LFS:LGS:LSS.html) (load far-pointer) instructions.  32bit mode can only use xmm0-7, so the first bit is always the required 1, making it not a valid `LES`/`LDS`.)

So yes, "Non Destructive source" is a phrase that Intel's manual uses.

---

#### Section 2.3.6: Instruction Operand Encoding and VEX.vvvv, ModR/M

> Some VEX-encoded instructions have syntax with less than three
> operands, e.g. VEX-encoded pack shift instructions support one source
> operand and one destination operand).
>
> The roles of VEX.vvvv, reg field of ModR/M byte (ModR/M.reg), r/m field of ModR/M byte (ModR/M.r/m) with
> respect to encoding destination and source operands vary with different type of instruction syntax.
>
> The role of VEX.vvvv can be summarized to three situations:
>
> - VEX.vvvv encodes the first source register operand, specified in inverted (1’s complement) form and is valid for
>   instructions with 2 or more source operands.  (This is the NDS case)
> - VEX.vvvv encodes the destination register operand, specified in 1’s complement form for certain vector shifts.
>   The instructions where VEX.vvvv is used as a destination are listed in Table 2-9. The notation in the “Opcode”
>   column in Table 2-9 is described in detail in section 3.1.1.  (*The part quoted in the question*)

- VEX.vvvv does not encode any operand (*clearly not updated for the FMA `DDS` case*).

The vector shifts in question are `VPS{R,L}L{W,D,Q}`, `VPSRA{W,D,Q}`, and `VPS{R,L}LDQ` (byte-shift), that use the `/r` field of `mod/rm` as extra opcode bits like some one-operand integer instructions (e.g. `and r/m32, imm8`).  e.g.

- `VEX.NDD.128.66.0F 73 /7 ib`  `VPSLLDQ`
- `VEX.NDD.128.66.0F 73 /3 ib`  `VPSRLDQ`

This is why the SSE versions are in-place bit/byte shifts, frequently requiring a movdqa instruction.  There are a few free opcodes in the `66 0F xx` SSE2 coding space which Intel could have used instead making these frequently-used instructions destructive.  I guess they were already stuck with their decision to use the `/r` field for the `0F xx` MMX version, though.  Making the new-with-SSE2 byte-shift insn destructive too was unnecessary, I think.  At least they managed to make one non-destructive shuffle, `pshufd`.

Comment: I think `NDD` stands for "Destination, Destination, Source", where the first 2 operands are read from and written to, and the last one is only read from.

Comment: @itzhaki: that doesn't fit: [`VPSLLDQ xmm1, xmm2, 5`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSLLDQ.html) reads from xmm2 and writes xmm1.  (vs. the non-VEX version `PSLLDQ xmm1, 5` which modifies xmm1 in-place.)